# Google Analytics API returns "Quota Error: User Rate Limit Exceeded." while only few thousand queries

Tags: google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api, dashboard, quota

I've created a custom dashboard(javascript @ localhost) which has about 10 views that are generated with Google analytics API and Google Charts .

Now that I've been debugging it for a while day or two it has started to return error  `"Quota Error: User Rate Limit Exceeded."` .

From google console it shows only 1,416 queries for the past 4 days.
And yet, the quota states following:

> Queries per day    50,000
>   Queries per 100 seconds per user 100
>   Queries per 100 seconds 2,000

Am I perhaps using some other Google API that has a lot smaller quota limits?
However, I couldn't find any other API from google console.

Answer (score 1):

Well, with correct keywords it was easy to find.
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/errors

One can change upgrade the limit to 1000 queries per 100 second per user.

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to [Google Developer's Console](https://console.developers.google.com)
2. Dashboard > Under API column, Click on **"Analytics API"**
3. **"Quotas"** tab > Change **"Queries per 100 seconds per user"**

   > from **100** to **1000**

src: [How to fix "Quota Error: User Rate Limit Exceeded"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q4XsRAIsQO0)